# Magento 2: Add multiple custom options to quote

Tags: php, magento, magento2, magento-2.3

I try to add multiple custom values to my product options while adding the product to cart. It works fine but the problem is that it loops through all options and stores only the last option to the $optionData array.

```
protected $customOption;
\Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\CustomOptionInterface $customOption
$this->customOption = $customOption;
```

Execute

```
$customOptionInterface = $this->customOption;
$optionData = array();
foreach ($product->getOptions() as $o) {
    $optionKeyIndex = array_search($o->getTitle(), array_column($optionsArray, 'name'));
    $optionData[] = $customOptionInterface->setdata(array(
        "option_id" => $o->getId(),
        "option_value" => "TEST"
    ));
}
$productOption = $this->productOption;
$extAttribute = $productOption->getExtensionAttributes();
$extAttribute->setCustomOptions($optionData);
$productOption->setExtensionAttributes($extAttribute);

$cartItem->setProductOption($productOption);

$newItem = $this->itemRepository->save($cartItem);
```

The reason for it has to be the "$customOptionInterface->setdata". Without it all individual array will be added to $optionData but of course I can't use it this way. Any idea what's wrong?

I appreciate your help :)